# Form Validation: AngularJS vs Jquery Validate

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for building a form.
Whats the best way to validate my form in a similar way to JQuery validate including custom rules?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ngForm` directive you have an instance of `FormController` with access to its methode `$setValidity()` which sets the validity state of a control. You may use it with `$parsers` in your directive.